# How do I format a number and increase the decimal point to the left with Plotly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plotly

My data has positive integers like 10, 20, 30, etc, but I would like the hoverformat to display them in percentages like 10%, 20%, 30%, etc. I tried just adding "%" to hoverformat, but it just adds two extra zeroes to everything.

Answer (score 1):

You could set hoverinfo to something like

```
hoverinfo: 'label+percent+name'
```

for a display with %.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up getting it with using "ticksuffix": "%".